# Formatting Last Name, First Name

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting

I'm doing this Project to extract data from an external .txt file containing 'employee names' and 'monthly sales data'. The format of the text file (complete file: is 'string' followed by 12 instances of floats)

```
last name, first name
45
23
34
....
last name2, first name2
78
32
23
....
```

My program is almost complete, but I need to format the 'last name, first name' to 'first name, last name' while printing the results. Here is the code of that part so you get a better idea. I'm using 'dict()' and .iteritems() to go through the 7 employees and their respective 12 month sales in the original file:

```
data = {} # dict: list of all values for person by person name
with open("SalesData.txt", "rt") as f:
    data_key = f.readline() # We remember first line (first man)
    data[data_key] = [] # empty list of values
    for line in f:
        # then we suppose every line is float.
        try:                             
            # convert to float
            value = float(line.strip())  
            # add to data
            data[data_key].append(value)
            # If it does not convert, then it is next person
        except ValueError: 
            # next person's name
            data_key = line
            # new list
           data[data_key] = []
for employee, stats in data.iteritems():
    print employee
```

Please note that 'employee' is stored as 'last name, first name' and I want to just switch it and get rid of the ','.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! I just started working with the dict() and sometimes I find it difficult to manipulate the data.

*UPDATE*
The main issues is not the actual formatting. This is what happens:
I used to after gather the data, format the 'last name, first name'

```
print ' '.join(employee.split(',')[::-1]).strip()
```

This work, but the result is printed in exactly this manner:

```
Shelly (first name)
 Adams (last name -also notice the blank space before Adams)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ' '.join(employee.split(',')[::-1]).strip()
```

Or

```
print "{0[1]} {0[0]}".format(employee.split(',')).strip()
```

Comment: This will print results as: 
'first name' and in another line 'last name'
any way to make them in the same line?

Comment: Are you sure about that? What exactly is in `employee`?

Comment: Yes, formatting 'employee' (Adams, Shelly) will give me an output of: 'Shelly' in one line and 'Adams' (with a blank space at the beginning) in another line. I'm not sure why this happens. Maybe the way the data is stored in that variable

Comment: What's the exact line you wrote?

Comment: 'employee' contains a string formated: (lastname, firstname). It exist in an external .txt list in the format of: (string) followed by 12 (floats) representing sales data. This repeats 7 times :: (7 employees). Let me know if you need more detail. I think the way the file is contained is what is giving me issues. Thanks for the help

Comment: In this line ` data[data_key] = []` you need to strip the newline from the name, so it becomes ` data[data_key.strip()] = []`

Comment: It will print the results in the same line (that's good) and the ',' is gone BUT the frommating 'first name, last name' is not there. Prints as original, 'lastname firstname'

Comment: Replace `strip()` with `strip('\n')` in `data[data_key.strip('\n')] = []`

Comment: Thank you! But still by adding the '('\n')' I face the same problem:  everything is in one line but the formatting is not correct - displays 'last name first name'. Sorry, I know it's a minor problem but it bothers me not knowing how to fix it

Comment: Then your names are switched in the file.

Comment: @ Burham Khalid, you are right. One specific instance was switched and mainly I was using that one as the sample to check :(! Sorry for the confusion. It does work perfectly, both once switched the space in between first name and last name is gone. Probably an easy fix...thank you so much for your help! I apologize for my lack of awareness sometimes

Answer (score 0):

```
employees = {}
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    lname, fname = infile.readline.strip().split(', ')
    stats = [float(infile.readline().strip()) for _ in range(12)]
    employees["%s %s" %(fname.strip(), lname.strip())] = stats
for employee in employees:
    print employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
print (' '.join((employee.split(',')[::-1])).strip())
```

Comment: Same deal, it will divide first name and last name in different lines. It does what I want it to do, it's simple. But the formatting output is what I can't get to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're retaining the line feed at the end of each name, so you have (for example) "last name, first name\n" instead of "last name, first name". Your formatting line is fine, you just need to modify the lines where data_key is set to:

`data_key = f.readline().strip()`

and

`data_key = line.strip()`

Instead of ending with `print employee`, use the line you'd already come up with:

`print ' '.join(employee.split(',')[::-1]).strip()`

Comment: Your suggestions make sense, but still by modifying those lines the output (still in the same line) is not reformatted to 'firstname' followed by 'lastname'